# React 18.2 with React-Search-Autocomplete

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use react-search-autocomplete (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-search-autocomplete). In my main page I have the following:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactSearch from '../Components/ReactSearchComponent'

export default function Welcome() {
   
    return (
        <div className="container body-content">
            <ReactSearch />
        </div>
    );
}
```

And the react search component looks exactly like on the npm page:

```
import React from 'react'
import { ReactSearchAutocomplete } from 'react-search-autocomplete'

function App() {
    // note: the id field is mandatory
    const items = [
        {
            id: 0,
            name: 'Cobol'
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'JavaScript'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Basic'
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: 'PHP'
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            name: 'Java'
        }
    ]

    const handleOnSearch = (string, results) => {
        // onSearch will have as the first callback parameter
        // the string searched and for the second the results.
        console.log(string, results)
    }

    const handleOnHover = (result) => {
        // the item hovered
        console.log(result)
    }

    const handleOnSelect = (item) => {
        // the item selected
        console.log(item)
    }

    const handleOnFocus = () => {
        console.log('Focused')
    }

    const formatResult = (item) => {
        return (
            <>
                <span style={{ display: 'block', textAlign: 'left' }}>id: {item.id}</span>
                <span style={{ display: 'block', textAlign: 'left' }}>name: {item.name}</span>
            </>
        )
    }

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                <div style={{ width: 400 }}>
                    <ReactSearchAutocomplete
                        items={items}
                        onSearch={handleOnSearch}
                        onHover={handleOnHover}
                        onSelect={handleOnSelect}
                        onFocus={handleOnFocus}
                        autoFocus
                        formatResult={formatResult}
                    />
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

However, I'm constantly getting the error "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')". How do I fix this?

Comment: I am having a hard time recreating your issue, in the code you provide there is no sign of `useState`

Comment: I'm kind of new to react so I don't really know how to debug it properly. I'm also seeing invalid hook call warnings in the console, and if I check where this useState is, it is in the code of react-search-autocomplete

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution on [codeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactsearchautocomplete-sg9h8o?file=/src/App.js).

I think in your case the problem is that you try to import

```
import ReactSearch from '../Components/ReactSearchComponent'
```

while the name of the components where you implement `react-search-autocomplete` is called `App`.

```
function App() {//some code}

export default App
```

I suggest you try to fix the naming of the component.

Comment: I also found the sandbox you linked here, but I can't figure out what the difference between my code and that code is.
I renamed the component App to ReactSearch but this did not fix the issue

Comment: Can you share your code in codeSandBox, please?

Comment: Now I am completely at a loss, I copy and pasted my code into the sandbox and on sandbox it works https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-galois-hhr8jp?file=/src/Components/ReactSearch.js

Any hints in which direction to look? I already checked dependency versions

Comment: @dgrs I think you should take a look a [ReactJS importing and exporting components](https://react.dev/learn/importing-and-exporting-components) there might be some useful information.

Comment: Make sure all your dependencies are up to date. You can update them using the following command: `npm update` or `yarn uprgrade`. Then delete your `node_modules` folder and reinstall all dependencies using `npm install` or `yarn install`.